# How to clean up additional object for use with flask

Tags: python, flask

The main looks like:

```
class SpecialObject:
    raise NotYetImplementedError

am = SpecialObject()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    def exit_cleanup(sig, frame):
        del am
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, exit_cleanup)

    app = MakeApp()
    app.run(...)
```

Then when I hit ctrl+c the gets 'am' referenced before assignment. Any idea whats going on?

Comment: What you've got above isn't quite legitimate Python.  There's no such thing as `NotYetImplementedError`, and simply running the code above would cause the `raise` to happen, and `SpecialObject` is never defined.  What does your code actually look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you have to specify the object being deleted comes from the global context. Adding the line shown below solves the problem.

```
def exit_cleanup(sig, frame):
        global am
        del am
```